# Coupling between data type class and reader/parser

Tags: c++

Assume that I have an Image class

```
class Image {
private:
  unsigned char* data;
  int sizex;
  int sizey;

public:
  Image(std::string filename);
};
```

and a class reading images from disk:

```
class JpegReader;
```

How do I design these classes when it comes to reading images via the filename constructor? I would like to reduce coupling and avoid circular dependencies.

One option is to led JpegReader be friend with Image class end let it write the member variables:

```
class JpegReader {
public:
  static void read(std::string filename, Image& image);
};

Image::Image(std::string filename) {
  JpegReader::read(filename, *this);
}

void JpegReader::read(std::string filename, Image& image) {
  image.data = readdata();
  image.sizex = readsizex();
  image.sizey = readsizey();
}
```

Another option is to have a constructor with all the member variables as argument:

```
Image(unsigned char* aData, int aSizex, int aSizey) : data(aData),
                                                      sizex(aSizex),
                                                      sizey(aSizey) {}

void JpegReader::read(std::string filename, Image& image) {
  Image tmp(readdata(), readsizex(), readsizey());
  std::swap(tmp, image);
}
```

Or have read() return an Image, and let the Image constructor do the swap:

```
class JpegReader {
public:
  static Image read(std::string filename);
};

Image::Image(std::string filename) {
  Image tmp = JpegReader::read(filename);
  std::swap(*this, tmp);
}

Image JpegReader::read(std::string filename) {
  Image tmp(readdata(), readsizex(), readsizey());
  return tmp;
}
```

How would you have designed it?

Comment: Image is basically a Bitmap class... JpegReader is a jpeg file reader that should return a Bitmap(Image in  your case). You can also have a generic ImageReader Interface....

Answer (score 1):

I would probably design it like this:

```
class Image {
public:
  Image(unsigned char* aData, int aSizex, int aSizey) { ... }
}
```

Abstract base class for image readers (allows you to pass readers around without knowing anything about them):

```
class ImageReader {
public:
  virtual Image read(const std::string& filename) = 0;
};
```

Concrete reader (no coupling to `Image` other than through the public constructor):

```
class JpegReader: public ImageReader {
public:
  virtual Image read(const std::string& filename) {
    return Image(readdata(), readsizex(), readsizey());
  }
};
```

Comment: In a real world example there would probably be more than 3 parameters needed in the Image constructor. Then it would be tempting to collect them all in a struct, and suddenly you have reinvented the Image class...

Comment: @Pibben: In a real-world example, the `Image` class would probably provide a lot more functionality than just storing two dimensions and a matrix of colours.